# Grab iframe src as user navigates external site

Tags: javascript, iframe

***this post may have already been answered but I cannot find it...***

I am creating a website that has one large `iframe` below a header.
This `iframe` will display a news [website](http://www.theage.com.au) and the user will navigate stories. Will it be possible for me to extract (and as such log) the source of said iframe as the user browsers stories?

```
<iframe src="http://www.theage.com.au" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** This would violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) concept and it would be a [severe security break](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy).

Think about it. You are the web site A and **you want to know the navigation details of your user on another site**. Not very secure, right?

Hope I helped!

Comment: Essentially it would be to allow the user to save their favourite stories on my site and share them with others. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: what about anything complicated? ;) also, sorry for necro